# Unity - Sprites Go Away In Scene View, But Not Game View

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite

*Coding Language: C#*

*Experience: I know my way around the basics*

I am currently trying to make a 2D unity game, and the goal is to break blocks. To achieve this, the sprite uses a "hit point" system, then deletes it's self when it hits zero. **BUT**, for some odd reason, Unity keeps the sprite loaded in the game view. It is gone in my scene view, so I know it is working. It just won't disappear in my game view. I have tried searching for some sort of refresh for the SpriteRenderer component, but I can't seem to find anything.

```
     private void Start()
{
    if (depthMultiplier == 0)
    {
        hitPoints = 3;
    }
}

void OnMouseDown()
{
    hitPoints -= 1;
    Debug.Log(hitPoints);
    if (hitPoints == 0)
    {
        GameObject.Find("PlayingScreen").GetComponent<Spendables>().gold += 1;
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

}

*Code I am currently using*

[*Sprites go away in scene view, but not game view.*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nl01U.png)

***EDIT - Might be worth nothing, I am using an Orthographic camera, and the object is also removed from the hierarchy***

Comment: does the object gets removed from hierarchy as well?

Comment: yes, it does get removed from the hierarchy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, fixed my own problem. After messing around with the camera for a little while, I found the *Clear Flags* property. Apparently, I had just turned this off instead of changing the Skybox.

[Clear Flags Property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OA20T.png)